# Any good VBA editor?

Tags: vba, excel, editor

I am just starting to learn VBA for Excel 2013. Just wondering if native VBA editor which come with excel 2013 is any good? I did some research, some people are saying that previous navtive vba editor function is insufficient, some people are saying that VB 6 is good enough for VBA.

Is there any better vba editor out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, the built in VBE is the best way to go. It has not changed in the last 10 years or even longer, but it is tightly integrated into Excel and does everything you need, especially as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

some time passed since you asked, but maybe someone else might find it useful. I looked for the same thing and couldn't find anything good until I found Notepad++.
It makes analyzing the code much easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).